# How to perform PCA with 2 different Landsat scenes

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat-7

I want to perform PCA on 2 sheets of Landsat imagery with different acquisition time and coordinates. Prior to processing, should I combine both into one scene (mosaicking process)? If so, how is the procedure pre-processing. Is it possible I could process them separately?

Comment: Where did you download the Landsat scenes?  What level of processing?  Have you done any atmospheric correction?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have good reasons for using PCA instead of, e.g., Tasseled cap.

PCA is very sensitive to the scene (that's why it is not used a lot), so you won't get the same result if you work on the mosaic than if you work on each scene separately.  I would clearly avoid woring on a mosaic if your images correspond to different seasons. If you have the same season, I can't tell which is the best (mosaicking/not mosaicking).However, if you do mosaicking, then I recommend atmospheric.

Comment: those 2 scenes have a different season, and both have on 1A level.. so regarding to your advice, should I avoid mosaicking process to perform PCA's. Can you show me a reference/papers that does PCA processing on that way?

Comment: yes, I would defenitely avoid doing PCA after mosaicking two L1A scene of different seasons.